# MySQL - When should I use a different table for similar data?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Lets say I'm storing play by play info for sports: basketball, football, and baseball.  The data basically fits the same model:

```
|  play_id  |  play_type_id  |  play_description_id  |  player1_id  | player2_id  |  player3_id  |
```

Those are the basic columns that each sport would share, but there would be several more.  Some columns would only be used by certain sports - like player3_id would be used by football for who made a tackle, but never by basketball - there wouldn't be a lot of these limited-use columns, but some.

Each game can have anywhere from 300 - 1000 rows (high estimate), so this table could grow to the billions eventually.

**My questions are:**

1. Should I just start off with different tables for each sport, even though there'd be about a 90% overlap of columns?
2. At what point should I look into partitioning the table?  How would I do this?  I'm thinking of archiving all the plays from the 2012 season (whether it be a sports specific table or all-inclusive).

Sorry if my post isn't more concise.  This is all a hypothetical case, I'm just trying to figure out what the disadvantages of having one massive table would be, obviously performance is a consideration, but at what point does the table's size warrant being divided.  Because this isn't a real project, it's hard to determine what the advantages of having a table like this would be.  So again, sorry if this is a stupid question.

**EDIT/ADDITIONAL QUESTION:**
On a somewhat side-note, I haven't use noSQL DBs before, but is that something I should consider for a project like this?  Lets say that there'd be a high velocity of reads and return time would be crucial, but it also needs to have the ability to run complex queries like "how many ground balls has playerA hit to secondbase, off playerB, in night games, during 2002 - 2013?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate it in multiple table. That way it is more flexible.

And if you want to make some statistics your are gonna be able to do more complex `queries` than if you have only one table.

It could look like this

Table **PLAYER**

```
ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME | DATE_OF_BIRTH
-----------------------------------------
1  | michael   | Jordan   | 12.5.65
```

Table **SPORT**

```
ID | NAME       | DESCRIPTION
------------------------------------------
1  | Basketball | Best sport in the world
2  | Golf       | Nice sport too
```

Table **PLAYER_SPORT**

```
SPORT_ID | PLAYER_ID | PLAYER_POSITION_ID
--------------------------------------------
1        | 1         | 1                    /* Michael Jordan play Basketball */
2        | 1         | NULL                 /* Michael Jordan play also Golf */
```

Table **PLAYER_POSITION**

```
ID | POSITION    | DESCRIPTION       | SPORT_ID
-------------------------------------------
1  | Middlefield | Any description.. | 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as your table structure is concerned the best practice is to have another table for Mapping play_id and player_id. There is no need of columns player1_id,player2_id,player3_id.  Just make a new table which has play_id and player_id columns.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just start off with different tables for each sport, even
>   though there'd be about a 90% overlap of columns?

I don't think that would help you much, the problem of growth rate for a single table will occur for segmentation-ed tables, this kind of distribution will just make a delay and will not solve the problem. Also you will lose integrity and consistency by violating [Normal Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms).

> At what point should I look into partitioning the table? How would I
>   do this? I'm thinking of archiving all the plays from the 2012 season
>   (whether it be a sports specific table or all-inclusive).

You need to use [logical database partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29).
I think a range partition on mach-date field will be helpful.
Documents about MySql partitioning could be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html).

Recomanding to use NoSql will need more information about your application, BTW NoSql will come with its pros and cons. Having a look [at the post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/215151/nested-entities-and-calculation-on-leaf-entity-property-sql-or-nosql-approach/215153#215153) may helps.

.